# Repeated boxing makes different references?

Tags: c#, equals, boxing, equals-operator

I try to understand this code:

```
double b = 3;
object o = b;
Console.WriteLine(o.Equals(3));//false
Console.WriteLine(o.Equals(b));//true
Console.WriteLine( o == (object)b );//false
```

1. Each new boxing makes different references of object b?
2. If 1. is true, why `o.Equals(b)` is `true`?
3. If `Equals` does not check references, why `o.Equals(3)` is `false`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yes, each time you box a value type, a new object is created. [More on boxing here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
2. `Equals` check for value equality, not reference equality. Both `o` and `b` are the same: a `double` with a value of `3.0`.
3. `3` here is an `int`, not a `double`, and `Equals` for different types doesn't do any conversion to make them compatible, like the compiler is usually doing. `o.Equals(3.0)` will return `true`.

Comment: Thanks! But why (double)o == 3 returns true? '==' operator makes convertion for primitive types?

Comment: @kris: it's not really the operator per se. The compiler will automatically widen 3 to a double so that the types match. It's not a runtime operation: 3 (int) here will really be compiled to 3.0 (double). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1e94s7e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for a list of automatic widening conversions.

Answer (score 2):

```
double b = 3;
```

creates a new variable in stack with value 3

```
object o = b;
```

creates an object in the heap which reference the same place of `b` in the stack **so you have the same variable with two references**  *this is boxing*

```
o.Equals(3)
```

is false because it creates a new  **anonymous** variable with value 3 **not b**

```
o.Equals(b)
```

is true because it's the same variable

```
o == (object)b
```

is false because `==` is comparing references in memory **addresess** but `Equals` compares the value of the variable itself

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx)
It explains all about equals behavior.

Comment: That says, " If the current instance is a reference type, the Equals(Object) method tests for reference equality", so reference of boxed b equals o. And why explicitly boxed b not equals o? (o == (object)b is false)

Comment: == is comparing references in memory address

Answer (score 0):

Every time an effort is made to convert a value type into a reference type, it must be boxed to a new object instance.  There is no way the system could do anything else without breaking compatibility.  Among other things, while one might expect that boxed value types would be immutable(*), none of them are.  *Every* value type, when boxed, yields a mutable object.  While C# and vb.net don't provide any convenient way to mutate such objects, trusted and verifiable code written in C++/CLI can do so easily.  Even if the system knew of a heap object that holds an `Int32` whose value is presently 23, the statement `Object foo = 23;` would have to generate a new `Int32` heap object with a value of 23, since the system would have no way of knowing whether something might be planning to change the value of that existing object to 57.

(*)I would argue that they should be; rather than making all boxed objects mutable, it would be much better to provide a means by which struct types like `List<T>.Enumerator` could specify customizable boxing behavior. I'm not sure if there's any way to fix that now without totally breaking compatibility with existing code, though.